# Which version of JScript does cscript.exe use?

Tags: windows, jscript, wsh

Which version of JScript does cscript.exe use?
Does it match any version of Internet Explorer, e.g. IE6?

Comment: Depends on the version of the Windows OS, see [JScript Version Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z6exc9e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Editing the question to add the solution is inappropriate here. Instead, post the solution as an answer, in the space provided below for that purpose. [Self-answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is acceptable here, but you need to do it properly.

Comment: @KenWhite it's already answered elsewhere, why encourage more duplicates? Flag it / close vote and move on.

Comment: @Lankymart: And how does the poster learn about how to properly self-answer if it's just ignored? Thanks for your input, anyway.

Comment: @KenWhite learning how to self-answer is fine. Learning how to self-answer a duplicate isn't, I'd rather they'd learn not to post duplicates before how to self-answer to be honest.

Comment: @Lankymart: As I said previously, thanks for your input. (It's not necessary; I've already voted to close as well. I'm familiar with how the site works. You can sometimes kill two birds with one stone, you know.)